# Configure and monitor Windows 2012 DHCP server with Powershell

Tags: powershell, dhcp, windows-server-2012-r2

We've recently been working with the documentation [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj590665.aspx)  to set up some access policies for a new DHCP server.

I've been able to successfully import 600+ records with the `Set-DhcpServerv4Policy -Name -ScopeID` command.

This seems to have wiped out the 2 records that were already in there, which leads to where I am running into issue.

I am trying to search the list that is now there to see if those MACs were included using `Get-DhcpServerv4Policy -Name "Allow Private" -ScopeId 192.168.16.0` but all I get is an condensed response of the MAC's.

`Name            : Allow Private
Description     : Allow access to Private Wireless Network
Enabled         : False
ScopeId         : 192.168.16.0
ProcessingOrder : 2
Condition       : OR
VendorClass     : 
UserClass       : 
MacAddress      : {EQ, 00-06-5b-22-xx-xx, 00-08-ca-e7-xx-xx, 00-0e-35-de-e5-xx...}e`

I've added the `-fl` switch and get the same results.

Windows Server 2008 R2 had an export feature but I don't see it here in Windows Server 2012.

If the MAC's aren't in the list I need to add them - and am hoping not to keep the list I have and just add them to it - but if I have to do that I will, unless there is an update command that I am missing.

Thanks for any thoughts.

Comment: Not sure what exactly you need but you can list out the MACs with `Get-DhcpServerv4Policy -Name "Allow Private" -ScopeId 192.168.16.0 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty MacAddress`

Comment: Thanks!  That actually answered both my questions because I was then able to test adding new macs.  If you out your comment as an answer I can mark it as such.

Comment: Ok, not a problem. Wasn't sure it was going to be enough information for your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to expand the MacAddress collection you can do something like the following.

```
 Get-DhcpServerv4Policy -Name "Allow Private" -ScopeId 192.168.16.0 |
     Select-Object -ExpandProperty MacAddress
```

I've also seen shorthand examples for expanding collections.

```
(Get-DhcpServerv4Policy -Name "Allow Private" -ScopeId 192.168.16.0).MacAddress
```